# Search for tweets with a phrase but excluding that phrase if it's within a URL

Tags: twitter

I'm trying to search for tweets that talk *about* NPR, but because Twitter searches the full text of URLs, my results include every tweet that links to NPR.org (a lot!). How can I search for tweets that mention "NPR", but exclude tweets that ONLY have NPR in the context of an npr.org URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my quick tests, `npr -npr.org` seems to work pretty well. There's definitely a difference between that and just `npr`. With the latter I do see links to npr.org, but none if I exclude it.

Of course, I'd also expect that to exclude tweets where someone has simply put `npr.org` in their text, but that may just be a side-effect you'll have to live with.

More information: [Twitter Help: Using Advanced Search](https://support.twitter.com/articles/71577-using-advanced-search)

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. Was hoping for a solution that would just ignore search terms in URLs entirely (so if someone mentions NPR AND links to us, it would still be captured in the search), but this gets me much closer to what I need.